# Data Dependency Profiling

Tags: linux, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm

I need to do a data dependency graph for some applications. However I need to highlight those dependences that in fact happened during a profiling execution of the application.

My question is: which tool can I use to do data dependency profiling on applications running in Linux over x86.

Comment: If you want to use LLVM, you can use opt tool when running your program together with an analysis pass. See http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#da-dependence-analysis . However, the dependencies are limited, depending on what you are trying to do.